# Copy map file on grunt with sass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, source-maps

I'm using usemin when building with grunt, and I use the following tasks on css: sass, concat, cssmin.
Is it possible to have a map file in the end in order to debug the code after it's built?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All these tasks support a map (usually through a `sourceMap` option), but it only maps their own output to their own input, so you would end up with at least 3 maps (if you manage to avoid naming conflicts):

- one from minified css to concatenated css
- one from concatenated css to separate css files
- one from each css file to the original sass files

I understand you're looking for 1 map from the minified css to the original sass files, correct? Unfortunately, afaik there is no support for that in the tools.